# LogIn using the Paypal Mobile SDK (Android)

Tags: authentication, cordova, paypal

i followed this guide: https://devblog.paypal.com/phonegap-android-sdk-plugin/
to integrate PayPal in my Phonegap Hybrid App.
If I pay with a credit card (in sandbox env) it works correctly and i can see the notification in my dashboard.
But if i press the login button, whatever user credentials i insert, it always return an error in login.

[image: login mobile screen]

So i navigate and i found this:[image]

So i want to know if i am doing something wrong or if it's really impossible to use this feature from mobile. In this case i wonder why the Java class allow to show a login button if it is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I needed to create some Sandbox account to log in.

Comment: I keep getting a "Consent Failed" message. Were you able to fully integrate this plugin into your app successfully?